# Access the attribute of custom type in adf valuebinding

Tags: oracle-adf

I got the following scenario:

In my pageDef i set a variable Binding with an own class let suppose the following Person class

```
public class Person{
    ...
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    ...
    getter..
    setter..
}
```

so i have in my pageDef the following Entry

```
<variableIterator id="variables">  
  <variable Type="my.class.Person" Name="chSupCase"/>  
</variableIterator>
```

now my problem is to access the attributs firstname and lasstname with expression language like

```
#{bindings.chSupCase.lastname}
```

I don't know, maybe this kind of access is not possible. In the web i don't find any example or document which forbid that access.

In the link https://forums.oracle.com/message/10729238 user 936645 show how the setting or accessing is programmatically posible

a second question is how can i bind the attribute firstname or lastname to a attributebinding

thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

If you're saying you want to define a java class and have it's attributes and methods available from the page binding, to be referenced via Expression Language (EL) then registering the bean as a managed bean is a good way to go.

1. Register this as a Managed bean in the task flow. adfc-config is a good default location.
2. List item Once the bean is registered with the task flow, you should be able to write expression language like:

   ## {scope.beanname.attribute}

As the bean is now registered, the expression editor (accessed via the Down Arrow to the far right of the field in the property editor) will "suggest" values for you and you can also select these from the list of beans and attributes in the expression editor.
You need to choose the scope for the bean when you register it. Default scope is request. I assume you understand JEE/JSP/JSF so you understand scopes.
Registered Managed beans, when used to support or "back" an ADF Faces page is called a "Backing Bean" in some docs. But that is just a Managed bean that is being used in  a certain fashion. It's still just a managed bean (managed because JSF 'manages' the lifecycle of the bean. It will new it up for you automagically the first time it is referenced in EL.)

This is a high level overview of the steps to take.
I would look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15523_01/web.1111/b31973/gs_jdev.htm), [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/learnmore/adfinsider-093342.html), and [here](http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/11gdemos/ADF_Insider_Essentials/AccessingBindingsFromJava/AccessADFBindingsFromJava.html) - although this is the reverse of what you want, but might provide some good background. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9991671/adf-invoke-operation-manually-from-code/10013217#10013217) might help as well.

Comment: Sorry i forget to say am develope a desktop client so i can't use managed bean. But to use a manage bean will be a workaround if the client would be a web client.

Comment: But I thing also about a POJO object to collect all the data and push it later in to the Row and call my method-action. I thing this will be similar to the suggestion with the managed bean. But i think if i use such a POJO or managed bean why i use adf. It will be better and easy to use my business service source instead of data controll. The reason why i use adf is to abstact from my source and the static objects.

Comment: Are you using ADF Faces with Swing? If so, note that this being deprecated. It would help us, who are taking time out of our busy days to help you if you would help us help you. Please include: version of product, exactly what parts you are using - add has 3 aspects to it: BC, Faces, Controller - and how you are using it.

Comment: Hi Joe thank you for taking the time. I don't use BC, only EJB with statless session bean with jdeveloper 11.1.2.2.0. I use ADF with Swing. What i won't to do is setting a variable with the typ of my class in the Executables under the variables iterator. This variable i will use as a parameter of a methodaction which is calling a EJB method which is use by the data control. At last i will bind the attributes of the variable to attributeBindings.

Comment: Festus thank for your help, but like i said in my last answer i use ADF with swing  so i can't use ADF Faces feature