# Executing two action listeners one after another in JSF

Tags: jsf, button, actionlistener, oracle-adf

In a jsff file in my ADF project I have a button for searching some information which is displayed on the page.

```
<af:button actionListener="#{bindings.ExecuteWithParams.execute}"
            text="SEARCH"
            id="button"/>
```

After that I have a button for editing the displayed information.

```
<af:commandMenuItem text="edit"
           actionListener="#{viewScope.bean.editPopup}"
           id="editBtn" immediate="true">
```

The main idea here is when `actionListener="#{viewScope.bean.editPopup}"` is executed then `actionListener="#{bindings.ExecuteWithParams.execute}"` is executed after it, automatically.

Do you have any ideas how it can be achieved? Thank you!

Comment: one method server side that does both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you can programmatically call executeWithParams in your ActionListener (editPopup)
Just add operation in your pageDef and call using OperationBinding

```
BindingContainer bindings = BindingContext.getCurrent().getCurrentBindingsEntry(); 
OperationBinding method = bindings.getOperationBinding("methodAction");  
Object result = method.execute();
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the single button click in a backing bean and call both methods from there. This [blog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9991671/adf-invoke-operation-manually-from-code) should help. Also [this](https://blogs.oracle.com/jdevotnharvest/entry/best_practice_invoking_business_services).

For the viewScope bean, there are [helper Static classes](https://sites.google.com/site/joeztechland/adf-links/how-to--in-adf/adf-utility-classes) that you can use to get a reference to the bean into your backing bean and then call the viewScope bean method there. Look at JSFUtils.java. This [blog](https://mjabr.wordpress.com/2011/12/09/access-an-instance-of-a-managed-bean-from-another-managed-bean/) is older, but might help as well.

Comment: You can also pass the second bean as a parameter to the first

Comment: @Joe, Thank you very much for the answer and the link.